# Infinite solutions of a diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

Given the Diophantine equation$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$
if the coefficients $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ are chosen among all the prime numbers, we have infinite equations. Is it possible to prove that the solutions of the infinite equations are infinite and countable?

Comment: If $a$ and $c$ are large enough compared to the other coefficients then the left side will be positive for all $x,y$ so there will be no solutions. Pietro has shown that if you take the full set of equations (or even a small chunk) you get infinitely many solutions. Simple cardinality considerations show it's impossible to have an uncountable infinity of solutions, even taking all the equations. I see no question at a research level here, so I vote to close. 

Comment: Could you tell me why is this interesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if e.g. $a=e=2,\, b=5,\,c=d=3,$ and $f$ varies among all primes, that equation has the solution $x=-y=f$, which already makes infinitely many (distinct) solutions.

Comment: (quite a stupid answer, but an answer)

Comment:   It's a start... 


Comment: actually I didn't mean to give a start  